# reading and removing a substring in the most efficient way possible, like array_pop() but for sub strings

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a string that could look like any of the following. In other words, it may have "in the morning" or "in the evening" but sometimes, it may not have anything.

```
"bla bla in the morning" or 
"bla bla bla in the evening" or 
"bla bla bla"
```

Does php have a function to both isolate and remove that sub string at the same time? something like `$last_in_array = array_pop($arr);` that both saves the last element into `$last_in_array` AND removes it from the array at the same time. Anything like that for strings for the scenario I'm explaining. If not, what's a really efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
function string_pop(&$haystack, $needle) {
    if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
        $haystack = str_replace($needle, "", $haystack);
        return $needle;
    }
    return false;
}

$string = "bla bla in the morning";
$return = string_pop($string, " in the morning");

var_dump($string);
var_dump($return);
```

**Output:**

```
$string: string(7) "bla bla"
$return: string(15) " in the morning"
```

Comment: If you want it to work different please clarify. A complete input/output specification would be nice. Or you can take what's here and write it :)